# How to improve the sensitivity of ESP32 for BLE scanning?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-ide, esp32

I am using ESP32 WROOM-32 board and programming it from Arduino IDE. It scans some BLE advertising devices. I have checked these data coming from a distance(Checked about 15 meters far from devices) on a mobile phone. But the ESP32 could only get data from upto 6 to 7 meters of distance. Is there any way to improve the sensitivity in the code?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: The ability of a Bluetooth receiver depends on two primary things: - the receiver's antenna (bigger is better, but the antenna has to be the correct kind for the frequency Bluetooth uses, you can just use a long piece of wire) and the amount of power the transmitter is using. The ESP32 shares its antenna between wifi and Bluetooth. Try turning off Wifi. And look into using an external antenna with the particular board you're using (or get a new board with an antenna connector or better antenna).

Comment: If your ESP32 WROOM-32 is one of those with PCB-antenna, then you will need one with the external antenna (see https://www.espressif.com/en/products/hardware/modules)